# Select area based on angle of elevation

Tags: qgis

I have a digital elevation model. 
I want to select the areas where the angle of elevation between a given peak and any other point on the map is bigger than a certain degree.

More simply put, I want to show where a certain mountain looks "big". Is there a way to do it in QGIS?

[image: angle of elevation]

Comment: Did you look at the Viewshed Analysis plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the viewshed tool will give the result you are looking for. One way to do this would be to create a point file of the mountain / feature you are interested in.

1. From this point create a euclidean distance raster (this raster will give you the horizontal distance from the point)
2. Now that you know how far you are from the point you can work out the height difference from the mountain to the observer. Create a new raster by subtracting the height of the mountain (try using the maximum height in metres above sea-level or feet above sea-level) from your base DEM, this final DEM will be the relative height difference between the observer and the mountain.
3. Use the raster calculator to then work out the viewing angle. Tan (Height raster / distance raster). So the relative height is x and the euclidean distance is y.
4. You output would be a raster with each cell being a viewing angle. Run a reclass to the select the angles you wish to use.

Just as a note, this result assumes the cell is orientated towards the peak you want to look at. What you may need to do is run a viewshed from the point you chose to have as the peak. Make sure you use the correct OFFSETS in the processing. The output from the viewshed will be a binary raster (0's and 1's), multiply this raster into your viewing angle raster. If the cell is not exposed to views of the peak it will be given a value of 0, if it can then the viewing angle will remain.

My thought process is based in ArcMap...but I am quite sure Q-GIS will have the same tools.

Answer (score 0):

[r.viewshed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.viewshed.html) in the Processing Toolbox